# Try/Catch block not catching my error when using nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, jwt, try-catch

This is my function:

```
interface MyUserRequest extends Request {
    user?: any;
}

type MyToken = {
    patientId: number
    name: string
  }

const SECRET: Secret = process.env.PATIENT_SECRET!

const patientAuthMiddleware = async (req: MyUserRequest, res: Response, next:NextFunction) => {
    const {token} = req.cookies

    try{

        const {patientId, name} = jwt.verify(token, SECRET) as MyToken
        req.user = {patientId, name}  
        next()
    }
    catch(error){
        throw new UnauthenticatedError('You are not authorized to access this route')
    }
}
```

Okay basically, what is happening above is that this function is a middleware, I have two users on my application, a patient and a doctor. This is the patient middleware above, which i put infront of the route as so:

```
app.use('/patient', patientAuthMiddleware, patientRouter)
```

So what happens is that when you log in, the middleware takes your token from the cookies, and gets the patient id after verifying it with jwt, obviously meaning that if a doctor logged in, the patient id wouldnt exist (doctors have its own middleware, which is having the same problem), It is meant to catch that error and respond with 'You are not authorized to access this route' as seen above. However, when testing with postman, when i try to access a patient route as a doctor, it brings out this message:

```
"msg": "Cannot destructure property 'name' of '(intermediate value)' as it is null."
```

which obviously means patientId doesnt exist on a doctor, however, it should be caught as an error and the right response should have been outputted, Also note that this exact code was working before as expected, It used to catch the error as expected, however, as i was testing it again this morning, it started doing this, Im not sure what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple things wrong.  First, this error:

```
"msg": "Cannot destructure property 'name' of '(intermediate value)' as it is null."
```

appears to be coming from this line of code:

```
const {patientId, name} = jwt.verify(token, SECRET) as MyToken
```

If so, then apparently, `jwt.verify(token, SECRET)` is returning `null` and thus you can do destructed assignment from `null`.  So, you'll have to either figure out why that is giving you `null` or write code to protect against a `null` value so you don't mistakenly try to use it.

Your confusion here arises because you aren't logging the actual error in your `try/catch`.  Instead, your code assumes you know why the error occurred.  So, always log an error by adding `console.log(err)` or `console.error(err)` like this:

```
catch(error){
    console.log(err);
    throw new UnauthenticatedError('You are not authorized to access this route')
}
```

That logging will also give you the specific line number in your code where the error originated too and will prevent confusion about what error there is.

FYI, it looks like `jwt.verify()` can give you `null` or an empty object if the verify succeeds, but there is no payload.  The reason for no payload would be something you would have to investigate elsewhere in your code.  It will `throw` when the verify itself fails.

---

Then, second you are using `patientAuthMiddleware` here:

```
app.use('/patient', patientAuthMiddleware, patientRouter)
```

This is Express middleware.  It expects you to pass it a function and Express does not look at the return value from that function at all.

But, you declare `patientAuthMiddleware` as an `async` function.  That means when you do this inside that function:

```
throw new UnauthenticatedError('You are not authorized to access this route')
```

the `async` function will catch that exception and return it as a rejected promise.  But, Express doesn't look at the return value at all.  So, therefore, your error will go undetected by Express.

---

It's unclear why you declared that function as `async` because usually that is done so that you can use `await`, but you don't show any use of `await`.  But, assuming you need it to be `async`, instead of throwing the error, you can just call `next(err)` with your error to make sure Express knows about it like this:

```
const patientAuthMiddleware = async (req: MyUserRequest, res: Response, next:NextFunction) => {
    const {token} = req.cookies

    try{

        const {patientId, name} = jwt.verify(token, SECRET) as MyToken
        req.user = {patientId, name}  
        next()
    }
    catch(error){
        next(new UnauthenticatedError('You are not authorized to access this route'))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the solution didnt work unfortunately. As i mentioned, The code was working perfectly before, i am just not sure what could have happened, I also dont think the problem is with the error catching method as i tested it with 'res.send('error') but it was still the same thing.

Comment: @gerard - Well, what I described absolutely IS a problem that needs fixing - your `UnathenticatedError` will be completely ignored and the request will get stuck (never advance past the middleware).  Perhaps it is not your only problem, but you don't show a reproducible test case so we can't see what else might be going on.  When you say "Code was working before", that could have been true with these lines of code only if `patientAuthMiddleware` was not an `async` function.

Comment: ah i see, okay then, i tried removing the async keyword, it still didnt work, how would you go about doing it?

Comment: @gerard - You have a separate error.  It's a programming error in your code.  The error `Cannot destructure property 'name' of '(intermediate value)' as it is null` is telling you that you have an error on a desctruring assignment line of code and it's never getting to your other error.  The FIRST thing to do is to ALWAYS log the actual error in a `try/catch`.  So, add `console.lor(err)` as the first line of your `catch` statement.  That will probably then give you the line number of your programing error.  I'm not sure where the error comes from myself.  You will have to log the error to see.

Comment: @gerard - When you blindly assume that you know what kind of error you are catching in a `try/catch` without logging what the actual error is, then you will get really confused when some other, unexpected error occurs and you can't figure out why the thing you think is causing the error isn't working.  In reality, the error is something else, so you're looking in the wrong place.   Always log the actual error.  Don't blindly assume you know what caused the error.

Comment: @gerard - I updated my answer with the info from my latest comments.